# Adding platform devices to Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, device-tree

While going through platform drivers for linux kernel, I came across platform driver APIs like

```
int platform_add_devices(struct platform_device **devs, int num)
static void platform_device_release(struct device *dev)
struct platform_device *platform_device_alloc(const char *name, int id)
int platform_device_add_resources(struct platform_device *pdev,const struct resource *res, unsigned int num)
```

As per my understanding the device nodes are added in the Device trees files. The kernel while
booting or the udev performs the matching of the compatible strings in Device trees node and platform driver and the probe() functions is called.

In the probe() we will get reference of the device tree node through **struct platform_device** structure which we can use to read the resource and other parameters of the device node from device tree.

So under what scenarios the above platform APIs are used?
Why we need to add devices to kernel using the above APIs.

Any inputs on this will be helpful.

Comment: Drivers can be built as modules not present at boot.  Devices can be hot-plug not present at boot.  Or both.

Comment: "*So under what scenarios the above platform APIs are used?*" -- Well, you may have come across a legacy API.  For the first routine, it seems to be used in recent kernel versions by only a limited number (or small percentage) of systems/boards to unconditionally install a few devices.  In fact use of this routine predates the use of Device Tree!  Do more research yourself with a cross-reference, e.g. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.39.4/A/ident/platform_add_devices